# How can I clear the variable after while loop is done

Tags: c++, variables

I'm writing a program that multiplies matrices. And here I have got two variables "i" and "q" which at the beginning are both 0. While the loops proceed variables ("i" and "q") change their values. However after the loops are done I need "i" and "q" to come back to the value 0, so the loops can repeat themselves for different "w" and "k" . How can I do so??

```cpp
 int wynik[x][z]; //table that holds the result of the multiplication
 int i=0;
 int q=0;
 int wyn=0;
 for(int w=0; w<x; w++)
 {
     for(int k=0; k<z; k++)
     {
         while((i<y) && (q<v) )
         {
            wyn = (tab1[w][i] * tab2[q][k]) + wyn;
            i++;
            q++;

         }
        wynik[w][k] = wyn;
     }
  }
```

Comment: Put this in a function, so `i` and `q` will be defined and initialized fresh each call?

Comment: Can't you just reset the values by doing `i=0; q = 0;` at the end of the loop ?

Comment: @CarlosMiranda I get the feeling that.s too obvious for the OP

Comment: Alternatively you can move the declarations for `i` and `q` inside the loop, which has the added benefit of preventing them from leaking to the surrounding scope.

Comment: If you only want to reset `i` and `q` only when nested loops are executed, you can just change the outer loop to `for(int w=0, i=0, q=0; w<x; w++)`

Comment: I hope `x` and `z` are `constexpr`, else you code is UB

Comment: If you declare variables in the narrowest possible scope, any "reset" will usually happen automatically.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site for *specific questions* about actual code.  You need to learn to debug your code.  Questions of the form "This code doesn't work" are not on-topic on Stack Overflow and are likely to be downvoted.  See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

set those to 0 after the outer loop is done:

```
 int wynik[x][z]; //table that holds the result of the multiplication
 int i=0;
 int q=0;
 int wyn=0;
 for(int w=0; w<x; w++)
 {
     for(int k=0; k<z; k++)
     {
         while((i<y) && (q<v) )
         {
            wyn = (tab1[w][i] * tab2[q][k]) + wyn;
            i++;
            q++;

         }
        wynik[w][k] = wyn;
     }
     //HERE
     i = 0;
     q = 0;         
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this movement doesn't improve anything. For instance, when I set tab1[3][3] and tab2[3][2], and for tab1 I fill table's cells like: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and tab2:1,2,3,4,5,6 in wynik[3][2] I should receive: 22,28,49,64,76,100 while the results are: 22,22,71,71,147,147. Idk mabey my way of thinking how I can multiplicate matrices is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the most natural way according to your current design would be to change the most inner while loop into `for (int i = 0, q = 0; (i < y) && (q < v); i++, q++)`. This lets for loop manage modification of `i` and `q` and both are inside the scope of the inner for loop since they are not needed anywhere else.

I would rethink the design. It sounds like a great example to study some algorithms. 
Just dropping this here ;)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm